Unable to Run GoReleaser with Pro Features
I bought a goreleaser pro, and don't understand how to properly run it with a new configuration.
I added a section for build DMG package, like this:
  dmg:
    - name: "my-repo-{{.Arch}}"

But when I run goreleaser release --snapshot --clean as mentioned in the Quick Start, it fails with the following error:
field dmg not found in type config.Project

I tried passing the goreleaser key as the environment variable GORELEASER_KEY, and as an additional parameter --key but without success.

goreleaser pro requires running a specific binary, try installing this one - https://github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser-pro

hmm, i installed it as usual via brew brew install goreleaser/tap/goreleaser

pro version requires a separate binary, updated the answer

ooo, thank you, can't find this in the instructions

You can check the instructions here, they're in the 'Pro' tab - https://goreleaser.com/install/#pro

yes, it works! it's not obvious that i need to change binary after purchase a license
